# Find the median of many variables in a set of netCDF files in python ( 5 giga of data)

Tags: python, file, bigdata, netcdf, median

I have data ( about 5 giga)  registered in many netCDF files ( a file per day during two years) . In these files there are 17 variables and I want to find the median of these variables. 
I have tried to concatenate the lists of each variable coming from different data to find the median but my computer crashes( in all I have 730 files. I have 17 variables with a dimension of 86400 each)
What is the efficient way to do that please. I have tried MFDataset but it crashes as well
Thank you

```
list_of_paths = glob.glob('path/**/*.nc', recursive=True)

time = list(())
a = list(())
b = list(())
c = list(())
d = list(())
e = list(())
f = list(())
g = list(())
h = list(())
i = list(())
j = list(())
k = list(())
l = list(())
m = list(())
n = list(())
o = list(())
p = list(())


for  path in list_of_paths:
      nc=Dataset(path)      
      a.extend(list((nc.variables['c1twa-a'])))  
      b.extend(list((nc.variables['c1twa-b'])))
      c.extend(list((nc.variables['c1twa-c'])))
      d.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu1-a'])))
      e.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu1-b'])))
      f.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu2-a'])))
      g.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu2-b'])))
      h.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu2-c'])))
      i.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu3-a'])))
      j.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu3-b'])))
      k.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu4-a'])))
      l.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu4-b'])))
      m.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu5-a'])))
      n.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu5-b'])))
      o.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu6-a'])))
      p.extend(list((nc.variables['c1tu6-b'])))
```

then I look for the median of each variable list

Comment: I think that xarray is your friend here, it should have no problems opening 5GB of data (it reads/processes data with Dask, so memory usage usually isn't a problem).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will work as it seems the memory requirements of your data are considerable, but in theory, if your files have a name format of something like

```
data_19810101.nc, data_19810102.nc
```

etc  i.e. you can list them using a wildcard with

```
ls data_*.nc
```

then you can calculate the median from the command line with this command:

```
cdo enspctl,50 data_*.nc median_output.nc
```

As I say you might have memory issues. Also, cdo needs to have all files open at the same time, and on some systems the max number of open files is restricted to 256.  Maybe you want to try the command first on a smaller number of files, or just one year 
e.g.

```
cdo enspctl,50 data_2005*.nc median_output_2005.nc
```

It is easy to also calculate other statistics over the files with the ens command by the way

```
cdo ensmax
cdo ensmin
cdo ensmean
cdo ensvar
```

to give some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using my lab computer with anaconda on windows, I don't know if I can use cdo on windows and if so in which way.

Comment: If you have windows 10 it is now super easy to install linux directly as a subsystem.  No need for wineservers, no need for cgywin, it is beautiful!  Just do a quick google (here's an example https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-linux-distros-windows-10) then away you go.  The linux is pure, so you can install anything there in the usual way: sudo apt-get install cdo for example.  I actually run python directly under the linux system on windows machines now.

Comment: I used to use wubix with windows 7 but I  cannot now since it is the lab machine not mine so the smallest  software should be approved before by n people. I am not even on an admin session. :/

Comment: apologies with windows 7 I don't know... Then you would need a wineserver or duel boot...  in any case, if you have python working, Bart's solution should do the trick and is less memory intensive (I did +1 for his soln which also uses your language of choice).

Answer (score 1):

A (very..) minimal example, using xarray and numpy. xarray can read/process data in chunks using Dask, so excessive memory usage is usually not a problem.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

f = xr.open_mfdataset('ERA5_land_201812*.nc', combine='by_coords')

u10_median = np.median( f['u10'] )
v10_median = np.median( f['v10'] )
# et cetera..
```

For your problem (with the recursive `glob`), something like this might work:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import glob

list_of_paths = glob.glob('path/**/*.nc', recursive=True)
f = xr.open_mfdataset(list_of_paths, combine='by_coords')

c1twa_a_median = np.median( f['c1twa-a'] )
# et cetera..
```

Comment: I have tried it, I get this error   ValueError: Could not find any dimension coordinates to use to order the datasets for concatenation

Comment: You might have to specify the `concat_dim` in `xr.open_mfdataset()`. See http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html

Comment: the dimensions of my variables are those of time variable which is mentioned in the file(  I have tried  concat_dim='time' and concat_dim=86400 which is the dimension of time but I keep getting the same error) sorry for my basic questions I'm a beginner with python, it is my first exercice  and thank you again for your help :)